# React - Trying to reference this.props inside reduce()-function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have little experience with JS and I'm following a video course on React. Most things makes sense but I'm having some trouble with reference scopes.

Here's what the tutor writes:

```
const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);

const total = orderIds.reduce((prevTotal, key) => {
  const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
  const count = this.props.order[key];
  const isAvailable = fish && fish.status === 'available';
  if (isAvailable === true) {
    return prevTotal + count * fish.price;
  } else {
    return prevTotal;
  }
}, 0);
```

He is using an arrow-function. It works of course.

I want to do the same but with writing a "normal" function, because for now I don't want to make any shortcuts:

```
const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);

const total = orderIds.reduce(
  function(prevTotal, key) {

    const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
    const count = this.props.order[key];
    const isAvailable = fish && fish.status === 'available';

    if (isAvailable === true) {

      return prevTotal + (count * fish.price);

    } else {

      return prevTotal;

    }

  }
, 0);
```

The problem is:

> TypeError: this is undefined

So there's a problem with the scope of the reference to *this.props...*

I got *this* to work within a *.map()*-function by passing it a second argument of

> ... , this)

from searching online about referencing *this*.

That doesn't work for the *reduce()*-function. So, what can one do in my situation? Again, I don't want to use the shorter arrow-function because it's like a shortcut I don't want to use when learning. I've searched online about scopes on *this* and also about the *reduce()*-function but the examples I've seen doesn't quite fit what I'm looking for, or I'm simply not savvy enough to use what they're writing.

Thanks a ton if you can help me out, regards / HW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bind as suggest upper or rewrite code like this:

```
const orderIds = Object.keys(this.props.order);
const { fishes, order } = this.props;

const total = orderIds.reduce(
  function(total, key) {
    const fish = fishes[key];
    const count = order[key];
    const isAvailable = fish && fish.status === 'available';

    if (!isAvailable) return total;

    return total + (count * fish.price);
  }
, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions has parent scope so this represents parent's `this` but simple function don't. You can tell the function about this using `.bind(this)`

```js
const total = orderIds.reduce(
  (function(prevTotal, key) {
    const fish = this.props.fishes[key];
    const count = this.props.order[key];
    const isAvailable = fish && fish.status === 'available';
    if (isAvailable === true) {
      return prevTotal + (count * fish.price);
    } else {
      return prevTotal;
    }

  }).bind(this)
, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, both of you!